# What's the best way to check return value of read and write system calls?

Tags: c, coding-style

I am interested in finding out the best way possible for checking the return value from read and write system calls on Linux. According to the man page, e.g for write:

> Upon successful completion, write() and pwrite() shall return the
>   number of bytes actually written to the file associated with fildes.
>   This number shall never be greater than nbyte. Otherwise, -1 shall be
>   returned and errno set to indicate the error.

For read:

> On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end
>   of file), and the file position is advanced by this number. It is not
>   an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes requested;
>   this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available
>   right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we
>   are reading from a pipe, or from a terminal), or because read() was
>   interrupted by a signal. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set
>   appropriately. In this case it is left unspecified whether the file
>   position (if any) changes.

So that makes me wondering:

```
if (ret < 0) {
    // see strerror
}
```

or

```
if (ret == -1) {
    // see strerror
}
```

Which one is the way to go, and why? Per man page, it seems to me like these are exactly same from functionality perspective. Is it right? Only difference I'm guessing would be that first statement should use a comparator, which would require more resources. Am I right with this assumption? Please share with me your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: I'd tend to prefer the first one as it's slightly more flexible (e.g. if there is an evolution of the norm and another kind of error is defined with another negative value), but I think it's just a matter of taste thus I don't think this question belongs to SO...

Comment: -1 is clearly defined as the error return value. So you should compare with exactly -1. If there was a `#define FILEIO_ERROR -1` you would compare with `FILEIO_ERROR`.

Comment: Because it is so clearly defined, there is not a case of defensive programming, in which you would compare `<0`

Comment: I also prefer the `ret < 0` check. A comparison `< 0` **may** result in less machine code, because it needs to check the sign only, it doesn't have to compare with a specific value. With `read` and `write` you should also compare the return value with the amount of data you wanted to write or read as the functions are not required to read or write all data in one call.

Comment: @Bodo I think Paul favors -1 check

Comment: Properly written API:s in C look like `result func (size_t* bytes_read);`. Crappy ones mix number of bytes with error handling and then force you to go check some global variable. Conclusion: these functions are written with bad API design and no matter how prettily you package them, they will still remain crap. There's no best way to package crap - just write some icky code with magic number `-1` and be done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'll look at it with performance in mind, using gcc 9.2 (x86-64):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **args, char **env) {
   if (argc < 0) {
       printf("ERROR!");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

will generate something like

```
.LC0:
        .string "ERROR!"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 32
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rsi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdx
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        jns     .L2
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
.L2:
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **args, char **env) {
   if (argc == -1) {
       printf("ERROR!");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

generates

```
.LC0:
        .string "ERROR!"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 32
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rsi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdx
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], -1
        jne     .L2
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
.L2:
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

so there isn't any difference performance-wise. With THIS compiler and architecture.

Anything else is personal opinion. I personally would go for "< 0" ... just because it catches everything.

Comment: I don't know x86 well, but are you sure the `cmp` instruction won't result in a different amount of cycles depending on parameters? The `cmp` with zero could take `0` as an 8 bit parameter, but the `-1` case would force it to be 32 bit.

Comment: In this case the cmp is the same and the difference lies with the jmp. And both use exactly one cpu cycle.

Comment: OT: the parameter `argc` will never be less than 1

Answer (score 0):

The style question  has been IMO answered by Maxine in his comment.

The efficiency is also better especially if compiler optimizes the code more aggressively

https://godbolt.org/z/MrTdqX

Comment: Talking about the overhead of a few extra move instructions next to a huge performance bottleneck like a `write` system call is ridiculous though...